# Sample of light weight data migration of iOS core data?

Tags: core-data, ios4, data-modeling, data-migration

Apple provide [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmMappingOverview.html) of light weight migration, here is good [sample](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/core-data_schema-versioning-and-lightweight-migrations/) prior to xcode4.

Seem like a little different in xcode4.

Thanks for any clues for simple samples in xcode4 to illustrate data migration of core data.

Answer (score 0):

Just note the addition of the options NSDictionary and NSPersistentStoreCoordinator initializer now has the options argument set from nil to options

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil)
    {
        return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"TradiesDB.sqlite"];

    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

    NSError *error = nil;
    __persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error])
    {
        /*
            ...
         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }    

    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```